# Is there a way to check if some generated code adheres to an interface when its not using the implements keyword?

Tags: java, interface, code-generation

I have some generated code that I can't modify. This also means, I can't add the implements keyword to the class declaration.

I want to implement a method that can take an instance of that class and assumes a number of methods are implemented there. Ideally, this should be enforced by the compiler

I could do this at runtime using reflection. But I'm trying to avoid it, because of the disadvantages of using reflection (performance, readability, ...). I'd also have to deal with runtime errors instead of compiler errors in case a class doesn't adhere to an interface.

Example:

```
  public interface Foo {
    boolean foo();
  }

  public class Bar {
    // Doesn't implement Foo interface but adheres to it
    boolean foo() {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public class Bar2 {
    // Doesn't implement or adhere to interface
    boolean bar() {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Now I have some method:

```
  public someMethod(Foo foo) {
    System.out.println(foo.foo());
  }
```

That I could call like this:

```
  someMethod(new Bar()); // I want something similar to this that compiles, Bar adheres to Foo
  someMethod(new Bar2()); // I'd like to have a compile-time error, Bar2 doesn't adhere to Foo
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: "implements an interface when its not using the implements keyword..." If it's not using the `implements` keyword then it's **by definition** not implementing the interface. You mean "coincidentally shares the same method signatures as an interface"

Comment: Short answer: No. You will have to `Bar implements Foo`.

Comment: More accurate short answer: you could use bytecode instrumentation

Comment: Does the developer know that "class Bar" has a method, "foo" which has the same signature as the method "foo" in "interface Foo"?  Are there are many such classes "BarA", "BarB", which all have a method "foo" (same signature) and you essentially want to create a method which can operate on each of the "BarN" classes, even though those classes don't have a common object hierarchy (which defines "foo')?

Comment: You could also use reflection.

Comment: Yes, I mean conincidentally shares method signature. updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap them in a delegating class which does implement the interface.

```
class NiceFoo implements Bar {
    private final Foo delegate;

    NiceFoo(final Foo delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    void bar() {
        delegate.bar();
    }
}
```

If you can't be bothered with the boilerplate, Lombok to the rescue. This is fully equivalent to the above, and will automatically delegate any methods added to Bar. If Foo doesn't have the relevant method, you'll get a compile-time error.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class NiceFoo implements Bar {
    @Delegate(types = Bar.class)
    private final Foo foo;
}
```